# NextJs Render facebook tags via Sever side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, next.js

I am working on a simple Facebook quiz application to learn React and NextJs.

The issue I am facing is with Facebook tags, when I share the user results It shows the quiz question page meta tags Because Facebook crawler renders the html before I add the new meta tags(The meta tags with answers base on user's provided data). How can I add the new description to the meta tags. Because the description is only available after the user click find my results button.

I am using **react-share** and NextJs **Head** to add meta tags

So, if the ShareResult variable has data load the results page otherwise load the question page

```
{ShareResult ? (
  <QuizResult response={ShareResult} />
  ) : (
  <CurrentQuiz id={props.query.playquiz} />
)}
```

Inside CurrentQuiz I load the Quiz to play and inside QuizResult I show the Results.

QuizResult page has all meta tags using next/head from NextJs

```
<Head>
    <title>Your Results</title>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://testurl.com" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta
      property="og:title"
      content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike"
    />
    <meta
      property="og:description"
      content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?"
    />
    <meta
      property="og:image"
      content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg"
    />
  </Head>
```

But this head is not generated from Server Side Because each user answer will depend on users data.
How can I add this Head so the Facebook crawler can read it?

Its my second day learning Server side rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching and trying many things i redirected the user to a new page using

```
Router.push({
            pathname: "/result/quizshare",
            query: {
              name: ShareResult.name,
              imageurl: url,
              quizid: props.query.playquiz,
            },
```

On the next page i get the props from server side rendering

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
  return { props: { query } };
};
export default QuizShare;
```

Also added meta tags With **NextSeo**